# How do I clean up my Puma Logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, puma

How do I clean up my rails logs so they don't show all this info about each individual asset fetched (particularly in development) and how long everything took? I'm using puma on rails 4.2.

```
source=rack-timeout id=7b3b3f3cd8d64909db09 timeout=13000ms service=2ms state=active
Started GET "/assets_dev/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-14 09:29:29 -0400
source=rack-timeout id=7b3b3f3cd8d64909db09 timeout=13000ms service=35ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=bef678d34175fcacf2b6dd timeout=13000ms state=ready

source=rack-timeout id=bef678d34175fcacf2b6dd17 timeout=1300ms service=1ms state=active
Started GET "/assets_dev/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-14 09:29:29 -0400
source=rack-timeout id=bef678d34175fcacf2b6dd17 timeout=13000ms service=79ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=b60818b0635ab2765de8ab4c timeout=13000ms state=ready

source=rack-timeout id=b60818b0635ab2765de8ab4c timeout=13000ms service=1ms state=active

Started GET "/assets_dev/logo2.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-14 09:29:29 -0400
source=rack-timeout id=b60818b0635ab2765de8ab4cb8928b40 timeout=13000ms service=80ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=b2839d080e992a9974d1984da0b1afcb timeout=13000ms state=ready
```

Answer (score 2):

The gem quiet_assets quiets all that asset noise in the development log. To remove the puma timing info, one can enter `Rack::Timeout::Logger.disable`. Though it would be useful to have timing info when there's an error, so not sure if that makes sense to do in production.

Comment: To be a bit more clear about removing the timing info, you would put `Rack::Timeout::Logger.disable` in **/config/initializers/timeout.rb** and make sure to `require 'logger'`at the top or you'll be seeing `! Unable to load application: NoMethodError: undefined method 'Logger' for Rack::Timeout:Class` in the logs as puma fails to start.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean narrow it down.

The available log levels are: `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown`

You can change the default by specifying it:

```
config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
Rails.logger.level = 0 # at any time
```

More info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels)

Comment: But I want it at the default level for the important info, I just don't need each individual asset request and definitely not all those times.